# Assign Distinct Object/Class in Linq to objects

Tags: c#, linq

I am doing following and it works:

```
    var resultsHeader = (from r in o select new { 
                        OrderID  = r.OrderID,
                        subtotal = r.SubTotal,
                        city = r.orderAddress.BilltoCity
    }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Look at the  **city = r.orderAddress.BilltoCity** Line, is there any way i can populate the entire object there...like this

```
var resultsHeader = (from r in o select new { 
                    OrderID  = r.OrderID,
                    subtotal = r.SubTotal,
                    Address = r.orderAddress
}).Distinct().ToList();
```

Basicly, I want to store entire OrderAddress Object into Address property, however **it does not come out as Distinct object**.

Comment: Is it LINQ to Objects? Is it LINQ to SQL? Is it LINQ to Entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use [`DistinctBy`](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs) from moreLINQ:

```
var resultsHeader = (from r in o select new { 
                    OrderID  = r.OrderID,
                    subtotal = r.SubTotal,
                    city = r.orderAddress.BilltoCity
}).DistinctBy(x => new { x.OrderID, x.subtotal }).ToList();
```

or `GroupBy`, which is part of LINQ already:

```
var resultsHeader = (from r in o
                     group r by new { r.OrderIs, r.SubTotal } into g
                     select new {
                         g.Key.OrderID,
                         g.Key.SubTotal,
                         Address = g.First().orderAddress
                     }).ToList()
```

**UPDATE**

Or, you can implement [`Equals` and `GetHashCode`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328/why-is-it-important-to-override-gethashcode-when-equals-method-is-overridden) on your `Address` class and use `Distinct` as you do now.

Comment: don't really want to use any other library, could it be possible without it? if i copy all the properties of Address objects then Distinct works just fine...its just when i pass the whole object it does not.

Comment: `GroupBy` does not require any additional library.

Comment: any example using Equalls?